# Unable to login in Kerberos Enabled Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop2

We configured our Hadoop clutser with Kerberos and everything started fine .We are trying to generate ticket for our hdfs principal using

```
kinit hdfs@HADOOP.COM
```

it is asking for password that we never configured although we are able to login using keytab file using

```
kinit hdfs@HADOOP.COM -t <keytab file location>
```

but now we wan the ticket that was generated using the keytab file to expire

I am very new in using Kerberos ,any pointers in right direction will be of a great help.

Comment: Can you able to generate ticket first? Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's a Linux box .How to check for tickets?

Comment: KRB5CCNAME is an environmental variable which is used to refer kerberos ticket. You can set this variable with some file location for ticket in the terminal before running kinit command. Then it will generate the ticket where KRB5CCNAME file location is set.

Comment: You can execute klist command from $JAVA_HOME/bin to list the kerberos ticket details. If JAVA_HOME set already, you can directly execute klist from terminal.

Comment: Yes i can see the tickets
    Ticket cache:File:/tmp/
    valid starting expires

Comment: Hope i answered for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the kerberos ticket details, execute the below command in terminal

`klist`

Make sure JAVA_HOME is set in bashrc file

Comment: I can see the tickets along with their start and expire time

Comment: Not sure about JAVA_HOME, because `kinit` is a C program (Kerberos was created years before Java...)

Comment: kinit, klist are available in java. For Hadoop, we are using java.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make any sense of that. On RedHat Linux `kinit` is installed via "krb5-workstation" RPM package. Nothing to do with Java. And by the way, the Java implementation of Kerberos seems quite lame, cf. https://github.com/steveloughran/kerberos_and_hadoop/blob/master/sections/jdk_versions.md  and  https://github.com/steveloughran/kerberos_and_hadoop/blob/master/sections/what_is_kerberos.md

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really mean by *"now we wan the ticket that was generated using the keytab file to expire"*.

AFAIK you cannot force expiration of a ticket, but...

- you can **delete** it completely with `kdestroy`
- you can **re-create** it (delete + create) with `kinit`, either in
  interactive mode (prompts for password then encrypts it to be shipped
  to KDC) or background mode (uses provided keytab, which contains a
  pre-encrypted password)
- you can **renew** it (shift the expiration date, as far as you don't
  bump into the max renewal lifetime)

So my best bet is that you just need to run `kdestroy`.